# Envoy has listener on both 0.0.0.0:9080 and <clusterIP>:9080

Tags: istio

I am playing with the Bookinfo example in the Istio guide. The deployment is successfully. And I am able to see the productpage.

When I looked into the detailed Envoy settings for the 'productpage' pod, I got confused. The return from istio-pilot for LDS shows that it has two listeners (among others), one watching `0.0.0.0:9080` and the other watching `172.17.0.9:9080` (which is the clusterIP of the productpage pod).

- The listener on `172.17.0.9` handles ingress traffic and routes everything to localhost, which makes sense.
- The listener on `0.0.0.0:9080` seems to handle all the egress requests to other services of the app, such as details, reviews. But it also handles requests if its domain is 'productpage.default.svc.cluster.local', and route it to the pod itself. So will this create a loop when a request is sent to the productpage svc?

I am sure the loop didn't happen. But just wonder what prevented it? or my way of reading the Envoy config is just wrong.

Also, I thought it is not allowed to listen to a specific interface once a listener is already created for `0.0.0.0` on the same port?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only one listener will actually bind to an OS socket. The other will have `bind_to_port` set to false
https://www.envoyproxy.io/envoy/configuration/listeners/listeners

Envoy can redirect internally to such unbound listeners.

Comment: Thank you! I see. I checked the LDS setting again. Looks like there is only one listener on port `15001` is binded. All the others are not.

So  then, in this example of Bookinfo, port `9080` is used almost every where for services/pods, how does Envoy do its job if it is only listening on `15001`? i.e. when a request is sent to `<productpage_pod>:9080`, who redirect it to port `15001`?

Also, when the `15001` listener redirect a request to port `9080`, does it redirect to `172.17.0.9:9080`, or `0.0.0.0:9080`, or both?

Comment: rephrase the 2nd question. if a request is made to 172.17.0.9:9080, which listener gets the redirected traffic, the one on 0.0.0.0:9080, or the one on 172.17.0.9:9080 ?

Comment: I think I got. `0.0.0.0` in the context of routing means the rest of the network other than the local. So a request to `172.17.0.9:9080` should just route to the listener on `172.17.0.9`